# Does -> skip change the behavior of the lexer rule precedence?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am writing a grammar to parse a configuration export file from a closed system. when a parameter identified in the export file has a particularly long string value assigned to it, the export file inserts "\r\n\t" (double quotes included) every so often in the value. In the file I'll see something like:

"stuff""morestuff""maybesomemorestuff"\r\n\t"morestuff""morestuff"...etc."

In that line, "" is the way the export file escapes a " that is part of the actual string value - vs. a single " which indicates the end of the string value.

my current approach for the grammar to get this string value to the parser  is to grab "stuff" as a token and \r\n\t as a token. So I have rules like:

```
quoted_value : (QUOTED_PART | QUOTE_SEPARATOR)+ ;

QUOTED_PART : '"' .*? '"';
QUOTE_SEPARATOR : '\r\n\t';
WS : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;  //note - just one char at a time
```

I get no errors when I lex or parse a sample string. However, in the token stream - no QUOTE_SEPARATOR tokens show up and there is literally nothing in the stream where they should have been.

I had expected that since QUOTE_SEPARATOR is longer than WS and that it is first in the grammar that it would be selected, but it is behaving as if WS was matched and the characters were skipped and not send to the token string.

Does the -> skip do something to change how rule precedence works?

I am also open to a different approach to the lexing that completely removes the "\r\n\t" (all five characters) - this way just seemed easier and it should be easy enough for the program that will process the parse tree to deal with as other manipulations to the data will be done there anyway (my first grammar - teach me;) ).

Comment: Dump your tokens to see what the lexer actually matched before even starting to check the parser.

Comment: As I said above, I think I did that. "in the token stream - no QUOTE_SEPARATOR tokens show up and there is literally nothing in the stream where they should have been".  I used the -tokens option for grun. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `skip` does not affect rule precedence.

Change the `QUOTE_SEPARATOR` rule to

```
QUOTE_SEPARATOR : '\\r\\n\\t' ;
```

in order to match the actual textual content of the source string.

Comment: I didn't think I needed to escape to match a carriage return, linefeed, and tab character. Why does it work for WS, but not for QUOTE_SEPARATOR?

Comment: Dump your source string to hex. The cf/lf/tab separator characters are being escaped by whatever is generating the source. So, `QUOTE_SEPARATOR` needs to match.

Comment: Depends on how the example was meant by the OP. If there are really linebreaks and tabs in the code then there is no need to double escape.

Comment: @GRosenberg This grammar is a learning exercise. I'd written my own parser many years ago from scratch (Its really a simple file). My original parser looks for that string and if I look for"\r\n\t" in notepad++ it will find the characters where I am expecting QUOTE_SEPARATOR. I will double check as you suggest. 

What is OP?

Comment: OP = original poster (that is you :-) )

Comment: @MikeLischke - if `there are really linebreaks and tabs in the code`, then the OP would not be getting the reported undesired results. Rather, it would work exactly as the OP thought it should.

Comment: OP - tools can munge control characters in the name of making them easier to see/handle. Only real way to be sure is to dump. Many IDEs support direct HEX/ASCII/BINARY examination of strings.

Comment: @MikeLischke Yep - I made a super small grammar to test with and found that copying and pasting test text out of gedit was stripping the \r. However, I believe there may be an issue with ANTLR4's handling of '\r\r\t'. I made a very small grammar to test just this problem:

Comment: @MikeLischke Yep - copy/paste from gedit was stripping the \r. However, there may be an issue with ANTLR4's handling of '\r\r\t'. I made a very small grammar to test just this problem:

`QP : '"' .*? '"';
QS : '\r\n\t';
WS : [ \t\r\n];`

and got a token string like this (no QS):

[@1,9:18='"lkjhlkjh"',<QP>,1:9]
[@2,19:21='\r\n\t',<'
 '>,1:19]
[@3,22:31='"lkjhlkjh"',<QP>,2:1]

When I changed QS to this:

`QS : '\r' '\n' '\t';`

I got a QS

[@1,9:18='"lkjhlkjh"',<QP>,1:9]
[@2,19:21='\r\n\t',<QS>,1:19]
[@3,22:31='"lkjhlkjh"',<QP>,2:1]

what do you think?

Comment: hmm...i guess i don't understand markdown - itried to make that pretty and failed . sorry.